# Docker and Postgis - How do I access shp2pgsql inside my docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgis

I am running postgres in a docker container using docker-compose and it spins up with no issue and I am able to connect to the database. But now I want to go into the container and execute the postgis `shp2pgsql` to load a shape file but the command seems to be nonexistent. Below is my code:

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: postgis/postgis
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
    volumes:
        - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/
        - ./postgres_init:/postgres_init
    ports:
        - 5433:5433
    networks:
        - ch_ntw

networks:
  ch_ntw:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.222.1.0/24
```

Getting into the container:

```
docker exec -it pg_container bash
```

Connecting to the db without issue using psql:

```
psql --host=pg_container --dbname=test_db --username=root
```

But then if I try to invoke `shp2pgsql` from bash I get the following:

```
 shp2pgsql -s 2263:4326 postgres_init/nyct2010_15b/nyct2010.shp | psql -d test_db

bash: shp2pgsql: command not found
```

I would think since this is a postgis container that the function should be accessible no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shp2pgsql` is a client package. The `postgis/postgis` image is the PostGIS server components only. If you want to use `shp2pgsql` or other client tools, install them locally on your host, or in another container.

Comment: Thanks, i opted to build it out in another container.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use same postgis/postgis image but doing am image including postgis installation in dockerfile:

create docker file "Dockerfile-database" :

```
FROM postgis/postgis:latest as builder
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y postgis
```

later you can create an yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
mypostgis_db:
    build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-database
        context: .
        args:
            - no-cache
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
        - POSTGRES_DB=mydbname
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
```

Last you can run the yml service created:

```
docker-compose up  --build mypostgis_db
```